# log console output where the same line is being updated

Tags: linux, shell

I'm running an application that on start updates the same line:

```
1 of 1,000,000 
200 of 1,000,000 
300 of 1,000,000
```

But the above is on a single line.

Every time the cursor is updated I'd like to write it to a log file so that I can observe the duration between updates.

This command seems to work for lines that were output to console before the number starts increment on the same line, but does not log the number updates.

```
command |& tee >(ts "%d-%m-%y %H_%M_%S" > play.log)
```

Is there a trick to log the state screen on update along with a timestamp?

Comment: Is the program writing to `/dev/tty`, or to stdout/stderr and just using carriage returns to move the cursor back?

Comment: To ask the question a bit differently: When you pipe both stdout and stderr to `tee`, does it not even update *to the screen* anymore (which would mean it's checking `isatty()` and deciding whether to log transient updates based on the result), or does it update to the screen but not append to the log (which would mean it's writing direct to `/dev/tty` and thus bypassing your redirections)?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of changes on a file by using `tail` and if you would like to prefix the contents with a custom input you could use `xargs`, for example:

```
$ tail -F file | xargs -I@ date +"%d-%m-%y %H_%M_%S --> @"
```

Or pass the output of your command:

```
$ echo "foo" | xargs -I@ date +"%d-%m-%y %H_%M_%S --> @"
11-08-18 15_53_53 --> foo
```

Comment: `xargs` isn't going to trigger on a sequence that has a `$'\r'` but no `$'\n'`, as is typical when a line is being overwritten in-place ("on a single line", as the OP puts it). And calling `date` once per line is really, **really** slow; once you've gotten to where you're actually picking out the lines, if bash 4.3 or newer is available, you'll get far better performance characteristics using `printf '%(...)T -> %s\n' -1 "$line"`.